# copy last value of a cell into a cell of another column

Tags: excel

In an Excel column, either there is one value (alphanumerical) that I should copy to the cell of the same row but in another column or there are more than one value separated by space and I should copy the last one in to the other column. The values have the same format, digits 5 or 6 followed by a character and three digits (8 or 9 chars). How can I copy correctly if there is one value in the other column and if there are more than one value the last one on 8 or 9 characters?

Thanks

[image]
Carol

[image]

Comment: Showing a screenshot of your excel sheet and the values would help a lot to understand what exactly your are after.

Comment: Consider than the values like
896523C546 1639486B432
are in a cell separated by a space or shift return (a line, but still in the same cell. So the format is to have7 or 6 digits from left to right and then a letter and again, 3 digits. 
The question is that how to take only the last value, in the above example 1639486B432?

Comment: Above, you can find a snapshot. So using just =RIGHT(A1, 8) it works if there are 8 alphanumerical values (B1 cell) and =RIGHT(A1, 9) if there are 9 (C1 cell). So we should just take the last value 110209Z16 no matter how long it is but the format could be on 8 characters like the value above 94139Z05 or 9 like the value underneath

look forward to your solution because none of the proposed solutions works and just copies the both values in the new column

Comment: see my answer below, does it solve your problem ?

Comment: it does like a charm. I just noticed that the digits on the left hand side of the letter could be any number (different length of digits like 3 or 8 or 10, perhaps shouldn't be fixe) and on the right hand side 3 digits. How could your code be modified based on this?

Comment: good, then we are doing progress here :) .. can you show a screenshot of what you mean about the 3 digits... I m not sure I understand it with words ;)

Comment: I added a new screenshot above. so I right hand of Z there are 2 digits 16 and on the left 3. 2 digits on right hand is fixed and the number of digits on the left hand side of Z is variable

Comment: Okey, yes I see ... you have 94139 and then Z and 05, and again you have 209 and then Z and 16. But what do you want to modify ? What is your expected result ? :)

Comment: the expected result is no matter what the last value is, 110209Z05 in the first screenshot and 209Z16 in the second screenshot should be copied in to a new column. Also note that there might be more than 2 lines in the opposite of first screenshot, for ex, 5 values or more or less in a cell and then, the last value should be taken. For ex, if there are the following values in 1 cell but in vertical positions like the first screenshot above

110209Z05
 209Z16
941309Z05
584959Z13

It's 584959Z13 that should only be copied to the new column. Hope it's more clear

Comment: I updated my answer, if there can be more than 2 lines in one cell...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101657/discussion-between-carol-and-mrsimplemind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(updated after additional input and chat)**

In one shot!

```
=IF( AND(ISERR(FIND(CHAR(10), A1)), ISERR(FIND(CHAR(32), A1))), A1, 
MID(A1, MAX(IFERROR(FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"#",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"")))),0),IFERROR(FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32),"#",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32),"")))),0) )+1, LEN(A1)- MAX(IFERROR(FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"#",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"")))),0),IFERROR(FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32),"#",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32),"")))),0) ) ) 
)
```

In words...

*if no line break or space is found then take the entire cell text, 
**otherwise**
find the last occurrence of a linebreak (char 10) **or** space (char 32) and take the text from that index*

[image]

Comment: both of them just copy whatever is in A1 and doesn't copy just the last value separated by other value with a space

Comment: If you want to copy, then you have to use vba but you tag the question as `excel` only.

Comment: copy the last value if there are multiple values in a cell. If there is formula that copy the value correctly, I can use it for all cells in a column (A1, A2,...) but dragging the lower-right corner of the first cell and won't need VBA, But the problem is that I still don't have a formula that get the last and not all values in a cell

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this formula.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" ",A1)),TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1))),A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Iget the same result as before whatever is in the cell A1 is just copied in another cell instead of taking the last value

Answer (score 0):

Use following VBA sub to copy to another column.

```
    Public Sub CopyAnotherColumn()
    Dim LastUsedCell As Long
    Dim stCopyItIt As String

        LastUsedCell = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        For Each rCell In Range("A1:A" & LastUsedCell)

            If InStr(1, rCell, " ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                stCopyItIt = StrReverse(rCell.Value)
                 stCopyItIt = Left(stCopyItIt, InStr(1, stCopyItIt, " ", vbTextCompare))
                 ReturnLastWord = StrReverse(Trim(stCopyItIt))
                rCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = ReturnLastWord
            Else
                rCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = rCell.Value
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```